# How to execute custom exe in MSBuild to set environment variable during property evaluation phase

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I am trying to import some props and targets file from a directory, which is a user-specified location. In order to determine this directory, I have some custom logic and I am trying to find a way to execute this in one of the props. I am unable to use the standard MSBUILD property functions to achieve this.

My end goal is to have a small UI that allows the user to specify this directory and the scope of this directory must be tied to a project i.e, there could be two different projects pointing to two different directory within a solution

Comment: Are you trying to use import like this?  <Import Project ="$(MyLocation)\Build1.Targets" Condition="'$(EnvVar1)' == '1'" />

Comment: Yes. That's how I am trying to import the targets and props too.

Comment: Even if you could do this, which I doubt, it might not work as you expect: when msbuild starts it will have it's own local copy of the environment block. Altering that while msbuild is running could yield unexpected results: some properties might be evaluated already using a different value than the new one being set. All in all I don't think this is the best idea. Alternative: create a target which checks if the properties are present and raise Error if not. Or else just force a proper build directory structure so all projects know where to find their property sheets. I'm using the latter.

Answer (score 1):

What about calling your build script again after you have fiddled out all your requirements? Every call to the `MSBuild` task where you put `$(MSBuildProjectFile)` as your `Projects` value will call your build file again and that call will have a new copy of the environment.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="EntryPoint" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0">   
    <Target Name="SetProperties">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <PropA>Something</PropA>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="EntryPoint">
        <MSBuild
            Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
            Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);OutputPath=$(OutputPath);"
            Targets="SetProperties;EntryPoint"
            Condition="$(PropA) == ''"/>
        <Message
            Text="Everything is set!"
            Condition="$(PropA) != ''"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This setup can be easily extended to execute some `Exec` task logic and forwards that output to a new call to the entry point.